# ionic framework call function in subscribe

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

mypage.html

```
    <ion-content class="backgray"
             #content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item no-lines
              *ngFor="let msg of msglist">
      <div class="chat-message"
           text-right
           *ngIf="msg.userpk == mypk">
        <div class="right-bubble">
          <p class="msg-date">{{msg.createDate}}</p>
          <span text-wrap>{{msg.content}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message"
           text-left
           *ngIf="msg.userpk !== mypk">
        <div class="left-bubble">
          <p class="msg-date">{{msg.createDate}}</p>
          <span> <span class="message"
                text-wrap>{{msg.content}}</span>


        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10>
        <ion-input type="text"
                   placeholder="Type a message"
                   name="message"
                   [(ngModel)]="sendmsg"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-2
               (click)="sendmessage()">
        <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

mypage.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.setmsglist()
  }
  setmsglist(){
    this.msglistsync()
    this.storage.get(this.talk).then((msglist) =>{
      if(msglist != null){
      this.msglist = msglist
    }
    })
  }    

ionViewDidEnter(){
    let dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions();
    this.content.scrollTo(0, dimensions.contentHeight,0);
    this.scroll=true;

    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      if(!data.wasTapped){
          if(data['chat']===this.talk){
            alert('a')
            this.msglistsync()
          }
      }
    });
    }


      msglistsync(){
        alert('b')
        this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
        alert('c')
          const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': token
          })
        };
          var data = JSON.stringify({"receiveuser":this.receiveuser.pk})
          let link = this.link+'/create/chat'
          this.http.post(link,data,httpOptions)
          .subscribe(data => {
          alert('d')
          var msglist = data['msglist']
         this.msglist = this.msglist.concat(msglist)
         this.storage.set(this.talk,this.msglist)
         }, error => {
         alert("error")
         });
     });
  }
```

get push alert a b c d  and `msglist` is changed

but HTML `msglist` is not changed directly

Once touch the footer, it changes.

I think sync problem.
how to fix it?

my Ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

Node : v8.11.0
npm  : 5.6.0 
OS   : macOS High Sierra

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its due to post service calling done into background thread so you need to refresh your data on main thread try below code:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

let self = this;
this.zone.run(() => {
     alert('d')
     var msglist = data['msglist']
     this.msglist = this.msglist.concat(msglist)
     this.storage.set(this.talk,this.msglist)
});
```

`this.zone.run()` will update your data on main thread.